# Understanding the Mechanism of Uploading Images to a Server and Retrieving Them on the Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, vercel

I have two API endpoints for image upload, one for the local server (http://localhost:8000/api/image/upload) and another for the live server (https://complete-auth-api.vercel.app/api/image/upload). I've encountered an issue specifically on the live server, where I'm receiving a 500 Internal Server Error with the accompanying error message:

```
import express  from "express";
import {addimage, getimage } from '../controller/addimage.js'
import multer from "multer";
const router=express.Router()

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb) {
        return cb(null,'./uploadphoto')
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
     return cb(null,`${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)   
    }
})


const upload = multer({storage:storage})

// upload a image
// http://localhost:8000/api/image/upload
router.post('/upload',upload.single('photo'),addimage)

router.get('/getimage',getimage)
export default router

addimage.js
    export const addimage=(req,res)=>{
    console.log("hello image")
    console.log(req.file)
    try {
        req.app.locals={
            photo:req.file.filename,
        }
        console.log("image uploaded")
        return res.send(req.file)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("image uploading failed")
        return res.send(error)
    }
    
}

export const addproduct=async(req,res)=>{
const headerToken=req.headers.authorization
   try {
        const token=headerToken?.split(" ").pop()
        const decode= jwt.verify(token,process.env.ACCESSTOKEN)
        // const decode= jwt.verify(token,process.env.REFRESHTOKEN)
        if(decode.role==='admin'){
            try {
               const photo=req.app.locals.photo
                if(photo===undefined){
                    return res.send("please select an image")
                }
                const data=req.body
                data.product_image=photo
                const new_data=await ProductModel(data)
                 new_data.save()
                return res.send("product added successfully")
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }        
        return res.send("you are not a authorized user")
    } catch (error) {
      return res.send(error.message)  
    }


}
```

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploadphoto/1704163351625_product-1.jpg'**

**Q. How can I handle image uploads on Vercel when I have the ability to create a directory for uploads locally but face restrictions on creating directories in the serverless environment of Vercel?**

I investigated Amazon and Flipkart websites and observed that they provide image URLs.

**Q. When uploading an image locally, I use Multer to generate a unique filename, and then I store this filename in MongoDB. However, I'm unsure about the process of creating a URL for the uploaded image. How can I generate a URL for an image stored in MongoDB in a web development scenario?**
[image]I would like to understand the mechanism for uploading an image to a server, particularly one that uses MongoDB, and retrieving it for the client.

**I've come across Vercel Blob Storage, but I'm having difficulty grasping its functionality. Can you provide a breakdown of how Vercel Blob Storage works and how it can be utilized in a web development context?**

Comment: How can we possibly give you any advice, when we haven't seen any of your code?  Do you have the same server code on both systems?  How are you doing the upload?

Comment: I have edited my question and provide source code

Comment: And does the directory "uploadphoto" exist on the remote server?

Comment: No, I am not getting this point that how to create "uploadphoto"

Comment: You control the server, don't you?  You copied code out there.  You create a directory exactly like you would on your local server.

Comment: I've made some edits to my question to improve clarity

Comment: Where, in this code, are you doing anything at all with MongoDB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256458/discussion-between-sunil-and-tim-roberts).

Comment: No, that's a StackOverflow feature that I strongly dislike.  However, you have now changed your text to ask an entirely different question.  It needs to be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to understand the mechanism for uploading an image to a server, particularly one that uses MongoDB, and retrieving it for the client.

The sequence will be something like below

- User upload an image from browser using `input` tag with `type=file`
- The form along with selected image is submitted to server via an api route with `enctype=multipart/form-data`
- Your server code will received the POST request. This can be handled with Multer as in ur code.
- Parse the form data and get image details.
- Generate an unique filename and us this as filename to write the file contents to Vercel Blob or Amazon S3 or in your server. (Storing in ur webserver is not supported by Vercel Serverless environment - https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-upload-and-store-files-with-vercel)
- Store the generated unique filename in mongodb so that we can retrive it later in your html code.
- The image can be later accessed by `<img src='YOUR-FILE-STORAGE-LOCATION/UNIQUE-FILENAME' />`

Check this to get more details on how upload image to Vercel Blob storage - https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-blob/quickstart#client-uploads